# If 0.99...=1 What about 0.89...=0.9?

Tags: sequences-and-series, decimal-expansion, infinitesimals

I notice the general pattern is that `?.??999...` equals to 0.??1 more than the repeating 9 part. Is it true?

Comment: Yes. It's true.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$x=a_0.a_1\cdots a_{n-1}a_n\bar 9$$
then
$$
x=a_0.a_1\cdots a_{n-1}a_n+0.0\cdots 00\bar 9
$$
and
$$
0.0\cdots 00\bar9=0.\bar9\times0.0\cdots 01=0.0\cdots 01$$
hence
$$
x=a_0.a_1\cdots a_{n-1}a_n+0.0\cdots 01.$$